# GitLab CI - passing JSON into a release-cli command with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to pass a JSON structure required to register a new release in GitLab, but I'm not sure how I should escape the double quotes. Here's a release job section from my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
release:
  stage: release
  tags:
    - windows
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  variables:
    ASSET_LINK_DETAILS: "{\"name\":\"${PACKAGE_NAME}.zip\",\"url\":\"${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/${PACKAGE_NAME}.zip\"}"
  script:
    - 'Write-Host "Creating release..."'
    - 'Start-Process -FilePath "release-cli" -ArgumentList "create --name `"Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG`" --tag-name `"$CI_COMMIT_TAG`" --asset-link ${env:ASSET_LINK_DETAILS}" -NoNewWindow -Wait'
    - 'Write-Host "Finished creating release..."'
```

Running this job returns an error from the `release-cli`:

```
Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -asset-link
```

What is the correct way to pass this JSON into the command in PowerShell?

Comment: Try qualifying the JSON string with some quotation marks: `--asset-link ${env:ASSET_LINK_DETAILS}` -> `--asset-link '${env:ASSET_LINK_DETAILS}'`

Comment: I tried wrapping it in escaped double quotes like this `\`"${env:ASSET_LINK_DETAILS}\`"`, but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the GitLab release documentation, there's a complete example there. PowerShell can be a PITA...

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/release_fields.html#use-a-generic-package-for-attaching-binaries

Here's an example:

```
- $env:asset = "{`"name`":`"$env:PACKAGE_NAME.zip`",`"url`":`"$env:PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL/$env:PACKAGE_NAME.zip`"}"
- $env:assetjson = $env:asset | ConvertTo-Json
- Start-Process -FilePath "C:\GitLab\Release-CLI\bin\release-cli" -ArgumentList "create --name `"$CI_COMMIT_TAG`" --description `"Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG`" --tag-name `"$CI_COMMIT_TAG`" --ref `"$CI_COMMIT_TAG`" --assets-link=$env:assetjson" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```